# Can't enter the SP:s website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Goal:
Enable to enter the website of central administration and its site collection.

Problem:
When I enter the website, I get a error message:

"Service Unavailable       HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

What course of action should I do?

- I'm a newbie in SharePoint 2013
- The error has to do with [web server](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can check the account used in the central admin application pool in iis (advanced settings).

I usually get these problems while either something is being deployed, or the app pool account password has changed, which will bring down the site repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your IIS application pool has stopped for some reason. Go into IIS Manager (via Server Manager) and select Application Pools and make sure the ones relating to SharePoint are started.

Comment: I have activated that was stop and unfortunately still the same problem